# path for sonar in jenkins when maven using ar config

Tags: maven, jenkins, continuous-integration, sonar-runner, sonarqube-5.0

I am new to CI as we are moving the project from waterfall to CI. I am able to do the maven build from the svn when using ear project pom.xml, but when tries to integrate the project with sonar, I have add the source project pom.xml in the scm path of the jenkins. then I am getting the following error.

```
ERROR: Failed to update "svn url..." org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: E175002: REPORT /svn/repos/projectname/!svn/vcc/default failed
at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:388)
at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:373)
at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:361)
at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.performHttpRequest(DAVConnection.java:707)
at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.doReport(DAVConnection.java:334)
at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVRepository.runReport(DAVRepository.java:1291)
at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVRepository.update(DAVRepository.java:833)
at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc16.SVNUpdateClient16.doSwitchImpl(SVNUpdateClient16.java:433)
at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc16.SVNUpdateClient16.doSwitch(SVNUpdateClient16.java:726)
at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.old.SvnOldSwitch.run(SvnOldSwitch.java:18)
at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.old.SvnOldSwitch.run(SvnOldSwitch.java:8)
at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.SvnOperationRunner.run(SvnOperationRunner.java:20)
at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperationFactory.run(SvnOperationFactory.java:1238)
at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperation.run(SvnOperation.java:294)
at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNUpdateClient.doSwitch(SVNUpdateClient.java:619)
at hudson.scm.subversion.UpdateUpdater$TaskImpl.perform(UpdateUpdater.java:161)
at hudson.scm.subversion.WorkspaceUpdater$UpdateTask.delegateTo(WorkspaceUpdater.java:161)
at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$CheckOutTask.perform(SubversionSCM.java:908)
at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$CheckOutTask.invoke(SubversionSCM.java:889)
at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$CheckOutTask.invoke(SubversionSCM.java:872)
at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:980)
at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:958)
at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.checkout(SubversionSCM.java:848)
at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.checkout(SubversionSCM.java:786)
at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1257)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:622)
at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:528)
at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1745)
at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:529)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:89)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:240)
```

`Caused by: svn: E175002: REPORT /svn/repos/projectname/!svn/vcc/default failed
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorMessage.java:208)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorMessage.java:154)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorMessage.java:97)
    ... 32 more`

Here I have add both source project pom.xml and ear project pom.xml in the scm path of the jenkins, I have a doubt which path does the sonar will pick.